# Two's Complement addition

Tags: digital-logic

I have a problem of adding two numbers in base of two's complement (6 bits!!!)

1100(2's C) + 0101(2's C)

I notice that the first number is starting with 1 which means it's negative
but since it's 6 bits, I have to change those two numbers into 6 bits and I have no clue how to find those numbers in 6 bits..

I need help please

Thank You

Comment: Has your professor covered sign-extension yet?

Comment: No never heard of them

Comment: Just have to use the two's complement

Comment: Okay.  Google it then.  Now that you have the term, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Just extend it to the left as much as needed, replicating the leftmost bit (sign bit).

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: 1100 becomes 111100. 0101 becomes 000101.

Comment: I understand that for the first number 1100, it's negative so the very first digit should be 1 but for the next one, why is it 1? doesn't it can be 0 too?

Comment: If you know how to convert a number to 2's complement, it would be easy to convince yourself that 111100 in 6 bits representation is the same as 1100 in 4 bits representation.

Answer (score 2):

1100 in four bits is -4

extending this to 6 bits, do sign extension to the left, adding 1's
because the left bit above is 1, and get 111100

this is still -4 in two's complement

0101 is 5 in decimal

extending it to the left, adding 0's, because the left bit is 0, 
and get 000101

adding these two together:

```
 111100
 000101
 ======
1000001
```

the carry bit (first one on the left) is discarded.

The result then is just 1, which matches adding in decimal, -4 + 5 = 1.

Comment: The truncated left most bit in your calculation result is not overflow. It's Carry (out).